# Directly access Revit DB API to Extract and Update properties without Revit Desktop application

Tags: autodesk-forge

In Design Automation Api for Revit - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/  I am very interested in this sentence "By providing access to the full Revit DB API, without the requirement of installing Revit on the desktop" .  The examples and tutorials refer to creating a revit plugin on my side, which requires desktop version of Revit. How do I extract and send data to the Revit DB API directly? My use case, is I want to Extract properties from Revit file  as csv or json file, enhance it, and push it back directly to Revit DB.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you quote is absolutely valid.

The application executed by the Forge Design Automation API for Revit (or DA4R for short) requires no installation of anything whatsoever on the desktop.

In fact, it requires no desktop at all.

The examples and tutorial do indeed refer to creating a Revit add-in on the desktop.

This is purely for development and debugging purposes.

If you are 100% certain that your Revit DB API code will execute faultlessly under all conditions, you can skip the desktop add-in and debugging and install it in DA4R right away.

Comment: Aha, I get it now, so it has 2 parts to it, 1. Revit DB API is a .NET SDK, and 2. once dll is tested, via REST you install. That was where I was stuck. Desktop is nice to have for coding and testing, but not needed to run the DA4R.

Comment: Exactly! I wish you lots of fun and success with DA4R!

Comment: Hi! So, to make it clear, I can make this tutorial (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/) without prevously compiling on Desktop Revit, i.e. skipping step 1, cann't I? Can I use a nwd model?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly skip step 1, if you get it right without debugging on the desktop. Debugging a Revit add-in may be simpler than a DA4R app. You can use an NWD model in Forge, yes, of course. Some of its properties will differ from the RVT ones, though.